# Method SetAttribute undefined for type HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

As the title says, i have a simple servlet, the problem is that while I can use classes and methods from "javax.*" the compiler says the symbol "SetAttribute" couldn't be find.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    request.SetAttribute("dummy_string", users.toString()); 
    //Compiler can't find SetAttribute Symbol
}
```

Comment: request.SetAttribute shouldn't this be request.setProperty? or setAttribute following the proper camelCase?

Answer (score 0):

Paul Bastide is right, it was VSCode which signaled the name as CamelCase in the lint. The name is in camelCase, for VSCode I saved the project, restarted the program and now it recognizes the camelCase version.